# facebook server sent event for live video comment only giving video owner comments

Tags: facebook, server-sent-events

I am using facebook server sent events using below documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events

I have proper user_access_token and page_access_token as I am owner of the live video.

But I receive these events only when video Owner (I) put a comment. I dont receive it when someone else put a comment. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is likely still in “dev” mode - that all these kinds of interactions then only work for users with a *role* in the app (you are not only the video owner, but the app admin here as well, I’m guessing?), is the *intended* behavior.

You need to make your app **live**, before this will work for all users.

---

Don’t forget that that also means you will need to submit your app for *review* of the features it uses and permissions it asks from users, if you have not done that already.